How to find the power of each individual bulb in a 50-bulb circuit
How to find the power delivered to each bulb of the 50 bulbs given in a circuit.
Given that the bulbs are rated (240V, 240W), connected in parallel to light a long corridor. The copper wires have resistance of 10 milli-ohms per meter (10m ohm/m). The source is a 240V independent ideal source. The distance between any consecutive bulbs is 5 meters. Assuming the wires connecting the source to the first bulb have zero resistance, I want to get the power of each bulb.
The issue is: I couldn't figure out the current values in each bulb as there is no way of using the KVL, KCL rules as there is no given diagram and it is difficult to manually draw a circuit of 50 bulbs.
Here is what I did to try to find the power:
Bulb resistance:
R = V^2 / R
=240^2 /240 = 240 ohms.
This is constant for all the bulbs.
Wire Resistance:
10 × 5 = 50 milli ohms.
=0.05 ohms.
This is constant for all the wires connecting the bulbs except for the first bulb.
Voltage Drop:
I calculated the voltage drop using this formula:
V = 240 - I (total) × R (wires)
But I didn't quite get the hang of it, I couldn't get the total current (I) in the circuit.
Power Delivered:
P = V^2 / R
I couldn't figure out the current through the circuit and there is no diagram of the circuit given.

Welcome! A valiant effort. Try to make a schematic of how you interpreted the circuit to be connected/stringed up. If I were your teacher and you misinterpreted the intended circuit but made your own and showed the calculation through each step, I would consider the effort in my grading.

Loop resistance or, resistance per copper wire. Either way, if you assume the wire has zero resistance you'll be out by only a few % and that's usually good enough for this type of calculation. It would be really easy to draw this in a simulator.

Are your bulbs linear (constant resistance)? Because most real bulbs are far from linear.

Unless you can find a shortcut, this is a long tedious process. Use a spreadsheet. Start with the farthest bulb and work backwards, calculating the resistance. Then use this to calculate the currents and voltages.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

With formulas shown:

Edit: I finished the spreadsheet and got the same answer as Spehro.
Edit2: More Details:
\$R_B\$ = Bulb Resistance
\$R_W\$ = Wire Resistance (both)
N = stage number, 1 to 50
\$R_N = (R_{N+1}\text{ }||\text{ }R_B) + R_W\$
\$I_N = \frac{V_{N-1}}{R_N}\$
\$V_N = V_{N-1} - I_N R_W\$
\$P_N = \frac{{V_N}^2}{R_B}\$
Be careful at bulb #1, it is a boundary condition.

"it is difficult to manually draw a circuit of 50 bulbs"
It's not that hard to draw in a program such as LTspice with cut and paste. The number of bulbs doubles in each iteration so we can draw a million bulbs in 20 iterations, in theory anyway.
I'm pretty sure there's a mathematical shortcut, as in solve the voltage for n+1 and n=0, however I never liked those puzzles and they don't have a lot of practical application. That's probably what your instructor is going for in this particular problem. In any case, whether you solve with spreadsheet, with code or with pen and paper, you might want to check the result with simulation.
Here's what I got (no guarantees it's correct, but if the process is done correctly and the final bulb simulation agrees with the calculation that's a pretty good check.

Qualitatively, the result is as you'd expect. The biggest voltage drop is across the wire pairs nearest the source since they are powering most of the bulbs, and the least drop is near the end of the string.
Here's what you'd get if you powered it from both ends:


I was going to say that there is probably some clever string to pull to make the problem unfold into an easily solvable equation but I think those usually end up filed away under "party tricks".

it can probably be collapsed to give the characteristic impedance of an infinite string of lamps.  but that will not give individual answers.

This is not a complete answer, but an addition to @Mattman994's.
The circuit can be simplified for analysis.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Simplified circuit.
It reads as though the problem is assuming tungsten bulbs and 240 V, 240 W bulbs should draw 1 A. In reality the further down the line bulbs will be running on lower voltage, be running cooler and will have lower filament resistance as a result. For exercises like this though, ideal bulbs can be assumed.
We can make a rough order of magnitude analysis though:

Assume, for now, that each lamp draws 1 A.
That means the cable feeding the first lamp carries 50 A. From V = IR we calculate the voltage at lamp 1 = 240 - 50 × 0.1 = 235 V.
Lamp 2 will get 235 - 49 × 0.1 = 230.1 V.
Lamp 3 will get 230.1 - 48 × 0.1 = ...

At this stage it becomes clear that the voltage is falling rapidly and our initial 1 A simplification isn't enough.
If I had to solve this as a real-world engineering problem I would use a spreadsheet along with some sanity check calculations.

With 50 sections treating this as a distributed R-R network would be a good approximation.
Even so I might be inclined to just do it brute force. Maybe faster, setting up the network in SPICE would be mechanical, and then you could include lamp nonlinearity if desired.

First, I'm going to get an approximation, when the number the bulbs is very large. At the end, I will provide some code for exact power calculation. So, consider \$R_a=0.1 \space \Omega\$ and \$R_b=240 \space \Omega\$ as the resistance of wire segments and the resistance of each bulb, respectively. Ignore distributed inductances/capacitances and other factors. Also, the total power is limited, no matter how many bulbs are present in such circuit configuration. Being \$Z_T\$ the total impedance (or resistance) seen from left to right in the circuits or stages, shown below:

For \$N=1\$:
$$Z_T=R_b $$
For \$N=2\$:
$$Z_T = \cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+R_b}}$$
For \$N=3\$:
$$Z_T= \cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+R_b}}}}$$
For \$N=4\$:
$$Z_T= \cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+R_b}}}}}}$$
That arranjement is know as Continued Fractions.
Taking \$N\to \infty \$, a pattern appears:
$$Z_T = \cfrac{1}{\cfrac{1}{R_b} +\cfrac{1}{Ra+Z_T}}$$
Solving for \$Z_T\$:
$$Z_T^2+Z_TR_a-RaR_b=0$$
or, in the present case:
$$Z_T^2+0.1Z_T-24=0$$
So, \$Z_T=4.8492 \space \Omega\$. Unfortunately, we cannot use that value along \$V_T=240 \space \text{V RMS}\$ (total applied voltage equal) in the determintion of power dissipated by the bulbs (with resistance \$R_b\$), since we must discount the power from wires (with resistance \$R_a\$). Next, we  get the voltages from the following nodes - named \$v_1\$, \$v_2\$, \$v_3\$, ..., \$v_N\$, trying to find a pattern, similar to previous work (structure repetition):

$$
\begin{aligned}
  v_1&=V_T \\
  v_2&=V_T\frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \\
  v_3&=V_T\frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a}\times \frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a}=V_T\left (\frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^2 \\
  v_4&=V_T \left (\frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^3 \\
  ... \\
  v_N&=V_T \left (\frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^{N-1} 
\end{aligned}
$$
The corresponding power dissipated by the bulbs \$P_N=\cfrac{v_N^2}{R_B}\$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_1 &=\frac{V_T^2}{R_b} \\
P_2 &=\left [ V_T\frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right ]^2\frac{1}{R_b} \\
P_3 &=\left [ V_T \left ( \frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^2 \right ]^2\frac{1}{R_b} \\
P_4 &=\left [ V_T \left ( \frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^3 \right ]^2\frac{1}{R_b} \\
... \\
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\boxed
{
P_N =\left [ V_T \left ( \frac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^{N-1} \right ]^2\frac{1}{R_b}
}
$$
As these terms are in geometric progression, it is possible to estimate the acumulated power up to \$N\$ stage, when adding them:
$$ \text{Pacc}_N= \cfrac{V_T^2}{R_b} \times \cfrac{1 - \left ( \cfrac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^{2N}}{1 - \left ( \cfrac{Z_T}{Z_T+R_a} \right )^2}$$
Below, a simple C program, for the APPROXIMATE calculation of the bulb power and accumulated power. In this case, It is important to increase the number of bulbs away from 50 (ex. 150 or 200), in order to get a better approximation :
/********* Resistive Network Power Calculator **********
************** Version with approximations *************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* PLEASE: INCREASE THE VALUE BELOW */
const int NB = 50;          /* Total number of bulbs*/
const double VT = 240.0;    /* Total voltage in Volts RMS */
const double RA = 0.1;      /* Wire segment resistance ((5+5)*0.01( in Ohms */
const double RB = 240.0;    /* Bulb resistance */
const double ZT = 4.8492;

int main() {
  int n;
  double r, p;
  double pt = 0.0;

  r = ZT/(ZT+RA);

  for (n = 1; n <= NB; n++) {
    p = (VT*VT)/RB*pow(r, 2*(n-1));
    pt += p;
    printf("Bulb %d: Power = %.4f W, Power acc = %.4f W\n", n, p, pt);
  }

   printf("\nTotal power: %.4f W\n", pt);

  return 0;
}

Finally, another C program, this time using a recursive function, for EXACT calculation of node voltage, bulb power and accumulated power:
/********* Resistive Network Power Calculator **********
*********** Version using exact calculations ***********/

#include <stdio.h>

const int NB = 50;          /* Total number of bulbs */
const double VT = 240.0;    /* Total voltage in Volts RMS */
const double RA = 0.1;      /* Wire segment resistance ((5+5)*0.01) in Ohms */
const double RB = 240.0;    /* Bulb resistance */

double pt;                  /* Total power in W */

double networkCalc(int nbulb, double zPrev);

int main() {
  networkCalc(NB, 0);
  printf("\nTotal power: %.4f W\n", pt);

  return 0;
}

/* Recursive function.
   Input: Number of Bulbs, Previous impedance value
   Output: Previous node voltage node
*/
double networkCalc(int nbulb, double zPrev) {
  double z, p, v;

  if (nbulb == NB) {
      z = RB;
  }
  else {
      z = (RB*(RA+zPrev))/(RA+zPrev+RB);
  }

  if (nbulb == 1) {
      v = VT;
  }
  else {
      v = networkCalc(nbulb-1, z);  /* New call */
      v = v*z/(z+RA);
  }

  p = v*v/RB;

  pt += p;
  printf("Bulb %d: Voltage = %.4f V, Power = %.4f W, Power acc = %.4f W\n", nbulb, v, p, pt);

  return v;
}

An output given by this last program:
Bulb 1: Voltage = 240.0000 V, Power = 240.0000 W, Power acc = 240.0000 W
Bulb 2: Voltage = 236.2975 V, Power = 232.6522 W, Power acc = 472.6522 W
Bulb 3: Voltage = 232.6936 V, Power = 225.6095 W, Power acc = 698.2618 W
Bulb 4: Voltage = 229.1865 V, Power = 218.8602 W, Power acc = 917.1220 W
Bulb 5: Voltage = 225.7750 V, Power = 212.3931 W, Power acc = 1129.5151 W
Bulb 6: Voltage = 222.4575 V, Power = 206.1972 W, Power acc = 1335.7123 W
Bulb 7: Voltage = 219.2327 V, Power = 200.2624 W, Power acc = 1535.9747 W
Bulb 8: Voltage = 216.0993 V, Power = 194.5787 W, Power acc = 1730.5535 W
Bulb 9: Voltage = 213.0559 V, Power = 189.1367 W, Power acc = 1919.6902 W
Bulb 10: Voltage = 210.1013 V, Power = 183.9273 W, Power acc = 2103.6175 W
Bulb 11: Voltage = 207.2342 V, Power = 178.9417 W, Power acc = 2282.5592 W
Bulb 12: Voltage = 204.4535 V, Power = 174.1717 W, Power acc = 2456.7309 W
Bulb 13: Voltage = 201.7579 V, Power = 169.6094 W, Power acc = 2626.3403 W
Bulb 14: Voltage = 199.1464 V, Power = 165.2471 W, Power acc = 2791.5875 W
Bulb 15: Voltage = 196.6180 V, Power = 161.0776 W, Power acc = 2952.6650 W
Bulb 16: Voltage = 194.1714 V, Power = 157.0938 W, Power acc = 3109.7589 W
Bulb 17: Voltage = 191.8057 V, Power = 153.2893 W, Power acc = 3263.0482 W
Bulb 18: Voltage = 189.5200 V, Power = 149.6576 W, Power acc = 3412.7057 W
Bulb 19: Voltage = 187.3132 V, Power = 146.1926 W, Power acc = 3558.8984 W
Bulb 20: Voltage = 185.1844 V, Power = 142.8887 W, Power acc = 3701.7870 W
Bulb 21: Voltage = 183.1329 V, Power = 139.7402 W, Power acc = 3841.5272 W
Bulb 22: Voltage = 181.1576 V, Power = 136.7420 W, Power acc = 3978.2692 W
Bulb 23: Voltage = 179.2578 V, Power = 133.8890 W, Power acc = 4112.1582 W
Bulb 24: Voltage = 177.4327 V, Power = 131.1765 W, Power acc = 4243.3347 W
Bulb 25: Voltage = 175.6815 V, Power = 128.6000 W, Power acc = 4371.9347 W
Bulb 26: Voltage = 174.0036 V, Power = 126.1552 W, Power acc = 4498.0899 W
Bulb 27: Voltage = 172.3981 V, Power = 123.8380 W, Power acc = 4621.9279 W
Bulb 28: Voltage = 170.8645 V, Power = 121.6445 W, Power acc = 4743.5723 W
Bulb 29: Voltage = 169.4020 V, Power = 119.5711 W, Power acc = 4863.1434 W
Bulb 30: Voltage = 168.0102 V, Power = 117.6143 W, Power acc = 4980.7577 W
Bulb 31: Voltage = 166.6883 V, Power = 115.7708 W, Power acc = 5096.5285 W
Bulb 32: Voltage = 165.4359 V, Power = 114.0377 W, Power acc = 5210.5662 W
Bulb 33: Voltage = 164.2525 V, Power = 112.4120 W, Power acc = 5322.9782 W
Bulb 34: Voltage = 163.1375 V, Power = 110.8910 W, Power acc = 5433.8692 W
Bulb 35: Voltage = 162.0904 V, Power = 109.4721 W, Power acc = 5543.3412 W
Bulb 36: Voltage = 161.1109 V, Power = 108.1530 W, Power acc = 5651.4942 W
Bulb 37: Voltage = 160.1985 V, Power = 106.9315 W, Power acc = 5758.4257 W
Bulb 38: Voltage = 159.3529 V, Power = 105.8056 W, Power acc = 5864.2313 W
Bulb 39: Voltage = 158.5736 V, Power = 104.7733 W, Power acc = 5969.0046 W
Bulb 40: Voltage = 157.8605 V, Power = 103.8330 W, Power acc = 6072.8376 W
Bulb 41: Voltage = 157.2131 V, Power = 102.9831 W, Power acc = 6175.8207 W
Bulb 42: Voltage = 156.6312 V, Power = 102.2222 W, Power acc = 6278.0429 W
Bulb 43: Voltage = 156.1146 V, Power = 101.5490 W, Power acc = 6379.5919 W
Bulb 44: Voltage = 155.6630 V, Power = 100.9624 W, Power acc = 6480.5543 W
Bulb 45: Voltage = 155.2763 V, Power = 100.4613 W, Power acc = 6581.0156 W
Bulb 46: Voltage = 154.9543 V, Power = 100.0451 W, Power acc = 6681.0607 W
Bulb 47: Voltage = 154.6968 V, Power = 99.7129 W, Power acc = 6780.7736 W
Bulb 48: Voltage = 154.5038 V, Power = 99.4643 W, Power acc = 6880.2379 W
Bulb 49: Voltage = 154.3752 V, Power = 99.2987 W, Power acc = 6979.5366 W
Bulb 50: Voltage = 154.3109 V, Power = 99.2160 W, Power acc = 7078.7526 W
Total power: 7078.7526 W


Great answer. The same argument can be used to derive the characteristic impedance of a transmission line - I definitely didn't expect to see it in a question about lightbulbs ;-)

@比尔盖子 Yes, thank you for pointing that out. When the number of bulbs is very large, that boxed expression can be used (no need to code). Otherwise, someone can use the second program (exact), which uses the fact that $Z(n-1)=\frac{R_b(R_a+Z(n))}{R_a+Z(n)+R_b}$ and $V(n)=\frac{Z(n)V(n-1)}{Z(n)+R_a}$. I think that a solution through difference equations (with appropriate initial conditions) is also possible, but perhaps it may not be worth, since in that case it would be very likely a computer-based solution, as well.


If I had to solve this as a real-world engineering problem

I would ask this question:  Unless the tolerance of the 240 ohm lamp resistance is better than 0.041%, is is reasonable to ignore the wire resistance?

No it is not, because the parallel resistance of 50 240Ω bulbs is 4.8Ω and the series resistance of 98 0.05Ω resistors is 4.9Ω. As a (very) rough approximation we halve that since the bulbs are distributed so we have about 2.5Ω and 4.8Ω so the final bulb might have about 158V across it, so very roughly 100W.
